# How to execute java source in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java sourcetree with eclipse projects. When I originally created them, everything works fine. The problem is that I had to switch machine and could only copy the whole working source tree to the new machine.
Now when I try to execute my projects in Eclipse it doesn't work, because Eclipse apparently doesn't accept a sourcefile as the main entry point.

The problem is as follows:

The package path looks like this:

```
package a.b.c.d.project;
```

Now when I import the project via the `New Project` and specify the path, then it uses the path of the project which is on a lower level and I get an error that the package is wrong.
When I import the whole sourcetree as a single project, the package path is correct, but then I can't launch the source. When I try to create a run configuration Eclipse claims it doesn't find any sources with `main` and the dialog box stays empty even though the sources are there and contain a main.

So what is the exact procedure to tell Eclipse to execute my Java files?

**Update**

An example from a source looks like this:

```
package net.arcor.sls.HibernateDB.helper.hibernate_database_record;
import ...
public class HibernateDatabaseRecord
...
```

and the error message is:

```
The declared package "net.arcor.sls.HibernateDB.helper.hibernate_database_record" does not match the expected package "helper.hibernate_database_record"
```

So apparently it now ignores that full package path because it set the projects directory as the package base. Since these projects were initially created as subprojects under the "net.arcor.sls" project I somehow need to reset the path.

Comment: By seeing your reputation it seems that you are more experienced that me i should not ask question to you but still i just want to know that if you are importing old project then why are you using new project instead of import existing project.

Comment: You either have to retype your package definitions in the classes, or fix the file/folder structur, so the defined packages are matching the file system. Could you give more specific information on your used packages and the respective file system? Just "a.b.c" is a bit abstract to handle. Also, does eclipse give you any error message? Could you please copy+paste them into your post?

Comment: When you do a `New Project` and import the project, open `org.eclipse.wst.common.component` file in `.settings` folder, and then check what's there in `source-path` or similar property. Or simply perform a textpad search for your main class's package `a/b/c` in your project. I am guessing the classpath is getting set wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps required to start working with a new Eclipse:

1. Copy project Source to workspace belong to new eclipse
2. Open eclipse And right click on `Project Explorer` and click `import`
3. In pop up click `import ...` and in `General`  folder click `Existing Project into Workspace`
4. In new window Browse project source folder in workspace
5. If there is no notification top of the window, click `finish`

Comment: Well, if it were that easy, I wouldn't have needed to ask the question. The problem is that the package path is no longer valid, even thgouh Iput the project in the same relative position. So I have to tell Eclipse somehow that the package path is different.

Comment: After looking at another installation that I found, I apparently was importing on the wrong directory level, so now it works.